# How to give margin left to table in itextsharp

Tags: c#, itext, pdfptable

I am using these code ...my tables are sticked to left side of document as i havent given any paddings in document...

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

But now i want to give margin left and margin right to my tables ...i used

```
outerTable.SpacingBefore = 20f;
```

it did n't work 
then i tried to give padding left to my cell it didnt work too..

```
outerCell.PaddingLeft = 20f;
```

Now my tables are sticked to left sides..how would i move them? Help if you have done trying moving tables in itextsharp...

pls check attached screen for reference

[image]

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way to get a table with a "left margin" is probably to wrap the table in a paragraph and set a left indentation on that paragraph

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
p.IndentationLeft = 100;
outerTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
p.Add(outerTable);
document.Add(p);
```

Answer (score -1):

I was trying to move table from document.left position but it didnt work then i tried to give padding in cell that even dont work too....

Then i changed in RoundRectangle class

where i changed `**rect.Left + 40f,**` this line in RoundRectangle() function and it worked for me.......

```
public class RoundedBorderLeft : IPdfPCellEvent
{
    public void CellLayout(PdfPCell cell, Rectangle rect, PdfContentByte[] canvas)
    {
        PdfContentByte cb = canvas[PdfPTable.BACKGROUNDCANVAS];
        cb.SetRGBColorStroke(42, 177, 195);
        cb.RoundRectangle(
         **rect.Left + 40f,**
         rect.Bottom + 1.5f,
        rect.Width - 20,
        rect.Height - 3, 4
         );

        cb.Stroke();
    }
}
```

Comment: `CellLayout` is called after a cell has been placed on the page, to allow you to still do some operations like painting a border or coloring the background. The position is already determined: the `Rectangle` that is passed contains the coordinates. So you can't tweak the margins this way. Maybe your offset on the left border will give the visual impression of a left margin, but be careful with the cell content. If the cell content grows, you might paint you left border through the content.